# Running COUNT in clickhouse immediately after INSERT returns 0

Tags: count, distributed, clickhouse

I'm running an INSERT query into a Distributed table of ReplicatedMergeTree with 2 nodes (single shard).
After the INSERT, I want to check the number of INSERTED records, so I run a COUNT query on the Distributed table.
At first, the COUNT returns 0. After several seconds (it can take more than a minute) the count returns the correct number.
I've checked using SHOW PROCESSLIST that the INSERT query has finished running.

Is there a way to verify that everything is in order before executing the COUNT?

Comment: --insert_distributed_sync arg                                    If setting is enabled, insert query into distributed waits until data will be sent to all nodes in cluster.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you may need to use the `FINAL` keyword. It is mentioned that one should try to avoid it, so you might be better off checking the table design and storage engine, but it could be good interim solution.

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/from/